# Clicking "X" on an Excel userform sometimes closes spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I'm writing a spreadsheet where double-clicking certain cells opens a userform.  When certain users click the "X" to close the userform, the whole workbook closes (which is not the intended behavior).  This happens if the cell has contents; if the cell is blank, the workbook does not close when the userform closes.

Here is the general code that calls the Userforms:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim requestID As Long
Dim rowCount As Long

rowCount = UsedRange.Rows.Count

If (Target.Row > 2) And (Target.Row <= rowCount) Then
    requestID = Cells(Target.Row, 1)
    Select Case Target.Column
        Case 2 To 4
            requestUpdateForm.populate requestID
            requestUpdateForm.Show

        Case 5
            initialSearchForm.populate requestID
            initialSearchForm.Show

        'etc, more forms using Case statements

    End Select
End If
```

I've seen this behavior before, except it was the opposite: clicking "X" to close a form opened from a blank cell closed the workbook, and this problem went away when I created a new workbook and copied all the code into it.

What puzzles me is that this error is occurring on one user's system and not on another's, even though both have identical installations of Excel.

Comment: Is there a QueryClose event in the form?  If so, what's the code in it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a problem with the installation of [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) in your system.

Try reinstalling or repairing the installation.

Comment: This is funny. I am not sure why this answer was voted negatively. See the question, the issue occurs in only one machine. That is surely due to the installation problem. While installing excel some add ins may not work properly these issue were reported in the Microsoft answer sites also. Try reinstalling or repairing the installation with tools available with Microsoft.

Comment: I am not sure why this was voted down, either, so I am voting it back up. Even if it is not the answer, it does not sound like a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for that gesture Remou. What I have seen is that some functionalities of excel do not work due to some installation problems.

Comment: I downvoted because I don't think it's the answer.  It's better to first debug extensively.  Then try Code Cleaner, removing other addins, deleting temp files, etc.  Another similar case yesterday - "Excel doesn't prompt to save unsaved files on Application.Quit" - was fixed by removing Solver on a machine where the code wasn't working.  Reinstalling should be a last resort after you've really tried to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: I agree with Doug's comments. Reinstall is a last step when pin pointing the issue has failed

Answer (score 0):

I solved it...by restarting--just shutting down the computer and turning it on again.

That's all.  I don't know why it worked but it worked.